# Box2D body lags/jumps when a camera is centered on it

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, box2d, interpolation

I'm trying to set the camera position to the position of a body, but when I do this, the body will jump very noticeably.  You can see this with the debug renderer but I have a sprite attached in my code. The jump is always in the direction that the sprite is headed.  I've got a fixed time step with interpolation, and I update the sprites position to an interpolated value of the current and last position of a box2d body every frame. Then set the camera to the interpolated position.

```
import java.util.Random;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Orientation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.JointEdge;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

public class GameScreen implements Screen { 
private static learnGame game;
private static OrthographicCamera camera;
private static FitViewport viewport;
private static Random rand;
private static BitmapFont font;
private static Vector3 touch;
private static double frameTime;
private static double accumulator;
private static float animTime = 0f;
private static float step = 1f / 60f;
private static boolean killBody;
private static Buttons buttons;

public static Player tom;
public static InputMultiplexer multiplexer;
public static Bodies world;
public static boolean paused;
private static Sprite tomSprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("chars/bob.png")));

public GameScreen(learnGame learngame) {
    GameScreen.game = learngame;
    multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FitViewport(40, 22.5f, camera);
    buttons = new Buttons(game, multiplexer, viewport); //HUD stuff
    world = new Bodies(viewport, multiplexer); //creates a box2d world
    tom = new Player(world.box2d, 10, 15, 1f, multiplexer); //creates a body with a CircleShape with a radius of 1.  Catches user input to apply forces to the body
    Assets.loadSprites();
    world.box2d.getBodies(world.bodies);
    font = new BitmapFont();

    touch = new Vector3();
    rand = new Random();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    learnGame.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    frameTime = 0;

    if (!paused) {

        frameTime = Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime(), 0.25); 
        accumulator += frameTime;

        tom.update(); //here I apply forces to the body that I attach a camera to
        generalUpdate(delta, touch, camera);
        updatePositions(); //get previous positions for interpolation

        while (accumulator >= step) {
            world.box2d.step(step, 6, 2);
            accumulator -= step;
            interpolate((float) (accumulator / step));

        }
        world.box2d.clearForces();

        learnGame.batch.begin();

        if (tom.getBody().isActive()) {
            tomSprite.setSize(tom.getHeight(), tom.getHeight());
            tomSprite.setOriginCenter();
            tomSprite.setRotation(Assets.tom.angle);//this doesn't work right but not the point.
            tomSprite.setPosition(Assets.tom.pos.x, Assets.tom.pos.y);
            tomSprite.draw(learnGame.batch);
        }

        learnGame.batch.end();

        cameraUpdate(); //update the camera to the same position as the sprite

    } else { //else pause the game
        learnGame.batch.begin();
        learnGame.batch.draw(Assets.pauset, viewport.getCamera().position.x
                - (viewport.getCamera().viewportWidth / 2), viewport.getCamera().position.y
                - (viewport.getCamera().viewportHeight / 2), viewport.getWorldWidth(), viewport.getWorldHeight());
        learnGame.batch.end();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.SPACE) || Gdx.input.justTouched()) { 
            paused = false;

        }

    }
    //destroy fixtures and bodies outside of the world step
    for (Fixture fixture : Bodies.fixturesToDestroy) {
        if (Bodies.destroyJoint == true) {
            world.box2d.destroyJoint(Bodies.joint);
            Bodies.joint = null;
            Bodies.destroyJoint = false;
        }
        fixture.getBody().destroyFixture(fixture);
        Bodies.fixturesToDestroy.removeValue(fixture, true);
    }

    for (Body body : Bodies.bodiesToDestroy) {
        world.box2d.destroyBody(body);
        body.setActive(false);
        Bodies.bodiesToDestroy.removeValue(body, true);
    }

}

@Override
public void show() {
    Assets.firstSound.play();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    viewport.update(width, height, true);
    Assets.reloadFont();

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    paused = true;
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}

@Override
public void hide() {
    paused = true;

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    Bodies.box2d.dispose();
    Bodies.debugRenderer.dispose();
    Buttons.stage.dispose();
    Assets.cFrame.getTexture().dispose();
    Assets.firstSound.dispose();
    System.out.println("disposed");
}

public void generalUpdate(float delta, Vector3 touch, OrthographicCamera camera) {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.PAGE_UP)) {
        camera.zoom -= 2f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        ;
    } else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)) {
        camera.zoom += 2f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
}

public static void cameraUpdate() {
    camera.position.set(Assets.tom.pos, 0);
    System.out.println("cam:" + Assets.tom.pos.x);
    camera.update();
}

public static void kill() {
    world.box2d.dispose();
    world.debugRenderer.dispose();
    Assets.cFrame.getTexture().dispose();
}

public void updatePositions() {
    for (MySprite name : Assets.spriteList) {
        name.prevPos = name.body.getTransform().getPosition();
        name.prevAngle = name.body.getTransform().getRotation();
    }

}

public void interpolate(float alpha) {
    for (MySprite name : Assets.spriteList) {
        name.pos.x = (name.body.getTransform().getPosition().x) * alpha + name.prevPos.x * (1.0f - alpha);
        name.pos.y = (name.body.getTransform().getPosition().y) * alpha + name.prevPos.y * (1.0f - alpha);
        name.angle = (name.body.getTransform().getRotation() * alpha + name.prevAngle * (1.0f - alpha));
    }
}
}
```

I have tested my interpolation implementation without the camera moving and it appears to work fine.  I've been able to test this on my desktop and on my android.  The sprite "jumps" a lot more on my android but it happens on both devices.  Not sure where I went wrong here, would really appreciate some input!

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, I know, but I just solved my Problem today.

I have implemented a fixed Timestep and interpolation, but my body lagged and jittered and jumped like there would be no tomorrow.

Please do following things to your camera Movement:

1. Use the interpolated Position from the body, NOT the original body position.
2. Use camera.position.slerp(x, y, z, alpha) to do a smooth movement. (You need to play a bit with the variables.

A really simple Example:

```
static Vector3 desiredPosition;
static {
  desiredPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
public static moveCam(Player player, Camera camera){
    desiredPosition.x = player.interpolatedPos.x;
    desiredPosition.y = player.interpolatedPos.y;
    camera.slerp(desiredPosition, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime * 5);
    camera.update();
}
```

and in your render do the following

```
render(float delta){
    moveCam(player, camera);   
}
```

(Instant position setting caused jitter for my moving Object)

I wanted to give up my project, because of this bug. But I managed to do it. I hope it'll help people out there.

€dit: A guess why the jumping body is happening:
The interpolated position is not synchron with the camera (set Position then update world(now interpolated pos is offset with camera), then draw)
But I'm not sure with this.